# When importing, why is the entire module loaded even when only specific portions are specified?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my programs memory footprint under control. I thought I'd start with the imports, as I'm only using 3-4 functions out of the rather large `PyObjC` library. However, I was a little surprised to see that importing specific pieces of a larger module had zero bearing on what was actually loaded into memory.

#### Memory Profiler output

loading the entire Quartz.CoreGraphics library on OSX:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    77                             @profile 
    78     7.953 MB     0.000 MB   def test_import_all():
    79    26.734 MB    18.781 MB    import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG
```

It pulls in the entire library at almost 19MB.

Trying to only pull in what I need gives the same 19MB results:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    82                             @profile
    83     7.941 MB     0.000 MB   def test_import_some():
    84    26.727 MB    18.785 MB    from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGImageGetWidth
```

So, it seems that specific imports have no bearing on what actually gets loaded.

Needing only a small handful of functions from an otherwise huge module seems like it would be a common use-case. Is there any way to load *only* what I need from a module into memory, or is this just the consequence of using external libraries?

Comment: As you basically already discovered, `from x import y` loads all of `x`, but only imports `y` into your namespace. So you can limit what's imported, not what's loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just how module loading works. The runtime maintains a collection of loaded modules, so the whole module is reachable even if you've only imported a few symbols. This has two desirable consequences:

- future imports of the same module are fast.
- any code at module-level that has side-effects, is executed only once (barring a module reload) instead of being executed a variable number of times depending what bits of the module are imported in what places.

It's also fairly inevitable if you consider that any function in the module can access the module namespace, either directly by using names from it or indirectly via `globals()`, `sys.modules[__name__]`, `eval`, or whatever. So barring some clever optimization to prove that particular functions don't do this (which Python implementations don't generally bother with), the whole module namespace has to be in memory.

Comment: Also, the functions you import most likely depend on other functions in the module; if it loaded only the parts you specifically asked for, you would have to know the internals in order to decide what exactly to load.

Comment: @tripleee: sure: examining the function internals to work out the dependency graph and trim unused functions would be a "clever optimization" indeed :-) One that you'd expect from for example a C compiler, but not from most Python implementations.

Comment: Having said that, it's not impossible that a large module could be broken into smaller modules which each make sense individually. If you can establish this, it's time for a (wishlist?) bug report to the module maintainer.

Comment: @tripleee: I agree, it's a reasonable feature request if you believe that a module can be sub-divided cleanly. Aside from source file proliferation, the downside of that (and the reason it might be reasonable to reject it) is that the lack of dependency among components might be considered by the developer to be an implementation detail, but you'd be asking for it to be fixed into the interface, because you'd want some sort of guarantee that each of the new sub-components doesn't just load all the others...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, because even if you think you only want one function, that function might need other functions (or classes, etc.) from the module.  A module is the smallest unit of code that can be loaded by an import.  If the module can be separated into multiple independent parts, and it's big enough that that would make a difference to performance, then it should be.  Otherwise, you can't import just part and/or it wouldn't matter if you could.